How can I patch holes in hardwood and carpet floor from outlets after rewire?
I have an early 1900s house that I just rewired. Many outlets were originally in the floor, which isn't how we do it today for a reason (I had an incident where an outlet box filled with water due to a plumbing leak). Now, I need to patch these holes.


I have considered putting an electrical outlet back and then a blank electrical cover, but these are ugly and not really strong enough for a floor. I also considered a metal plate with a carpet patch on top, but I have never patched carpet before.
Is there any easy solution here that would be strong enough for a floor and look decent?

Is there carpet on the floor? Sure looks like a simple case of needing to patch a wooden floor with wood.

If the room is carpeted, just screw some wood in from the underside to support enough wood to plug the hole (which doesn't need to look particularly good, since you won't see it) and put carpet back over the top. You'll probably need new carpet to make that look good, unless you saved a bunch of the carpet scraps for patching with.
If it did need to look good without carpet, same thing with more care, and matching top layer of wood; or contrasting nice wood patch if matching proves impossible.

If it's not carpeted, is there a closet from which you can "steal" some unperforated boards?  You can replace with mismatched boards, or boards that don't match quite as well (because who cares—it's a closet).
